# Android Typeface createFromFile

Tags: java, android, fonts, typeface

I tried this. Getting some exception. Posted my Logcat below

```
 textView.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("name"));
 String path= getIntent().getStringExtra("font");
 Typeface tf=Typeface.createFromFile(path);
 textView.setTypeface(tf);
```

**Logcat**

> addFont failed to create font
>   http://server/font/public/1526331572-font.otf
>       05-15 14:55:51.094 4245-4245/com.nani.font E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>           Process: com.nani.font, PID: 4245
>           java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nani.font/com.nani.font.FinalActivity}:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Font not found
>   http://server/font/public/1526331572-font.otf
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2555)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474)
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)
>            Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Font not found http://server/font/public/1526331572-font.otf
>               at android.graphics.Typeface.createFromFile(Typeface.java:250)
>               at com.nani.font.FinalActivity.onCreate(FinalActivity.java:29)
>               at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6092)
>               at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1112)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2502)
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2629) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:182) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1474) 
>               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111) 
>               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194) 
>               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033) 
>               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)

Can someone help me with this.

Comment: post your logcat not links... which are not working btw.

Comment: @Sam.  updated             .

Comment: it says font not found. make sure path exists and there is font in that path...

Comment: yeah..i'm uploading font from server and trying get that font in recyclerview @Sam.

Comment: Is this a font on cloud or local font?

Comment: . cloud @Khemraj

Comment: `http://server/font/public/1526331572-font.otf` is this your font?

Comment: yeah......   @Khemraj

Comment: I opened this url, there is nothing actually, did you opened it in browser?

Comment: actually that's my local server    @Khemraj